# Windows executable to install IE toolbar button

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, toolbar

I have created necessary .reg file for the toolbar button as per the link below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854%28VS.85%29.aspx

I would like to bundle .reg file and icon files into an executable that can be used for one-click install.

What is the best way to build something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InfTool](http://www.inner-smile.com/dl_inf.htm) is the closest that comes to mind. It allows you to bundle an .inf file and related files into single executable. You would have to rewrite the .reg file into .inf "script" though.

Update: There's a [tool](http://www.ubcd4win.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=4966) to convert the .reg file into .inf, you just have to add the files section then and run InfTool on it.

Comment: I gave inftool a try. Great tool. It can even import reg files. 

Need to buy pro version though to be able to install into "Program Files" and few other locations.

Great find.